# DOM - append in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add rows `<tr>` in to a table a any level(Top/Bottom/In between) using `Javascript/jQuery` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to append tr to top of table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683420/how-to-append-tr-to-top-of-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(html).insertBefore($('table tr').eq(index));
```

Will insert some `html` before the `tr` with index specified.

## [A small demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j8det/3/)

Comment: Is the order of the `tr`s in `$('table tr')` guaranteed?

Comment: `eq` "Reduce[s] the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.", but can the order of the set of matched elements in the results `$('table tr')` be the same each time and be from the top of the table each time?

Comment: as far i know the order of the jQuery objects in `$('table tr')` will be the same as the order of `tr`s in the `table`, because jQuery traverses down the `table` node to make the object `$('table tr')`

Comment: but how do I put in the table element in this line? $('<tr><td>test</td></tr>').insertBefore(tbl_elm.eq(0));

Answer (score 0):

- to append to the bottom:

you have nothing to do, because you just have to find the parent element and then append it.

- to append to the top:

well, it is more complicated, but I think is possible. One way is following:

find the parent element from the rows and read all rows into an extra variable. Fortunatly the result will be an array of object. Then create a new row element and use the method `unshift()` to put this at the begin of the array. Clean table's body and then add each element to body again.

Comment: @StuperUser because I didn't know that method, although this method exists since jquery 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/